# Move root partition to another disk

Tags: linux, partition, root-filesystem

Below is my `df -h` output.

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on  
/dev/xvda1       20G   18G  1.2G  95% /  
tmpfs           2.0G     0  2.0G   0% /dev/shm  
/dev/xvda2      138G  4.4G  127G   4% /opt/xxxx
```

How can I move / partition on /dev/xvda2 to use free space from it?

If that is not possible then how can I mount only /opt on xvda2 instead of /opt/xxxx without loosing data under /opt/?

Answer (score 1):

If you don't actually need two partitions, the easiest way would be to boot a rescue CD called [gparted](http://gparted.org/).  Then, get a rool shell and:

```
mkdir -p /mnt
mkdir -p /oldroot
mount /dev/xvda1 /oldroot
mount /dev/xvda2 /mnt/
mkdir /mnt/opt
mv /mnt/* /mnt/opt
rsync -avx /oldroot /mnt

# now edit /mnt/etc/fstab to comment out or delete the /opt line

umount /mnt /oldroot
```

/dev/xvda2 should now contain both the old / and /opt filesystems.  The trick now is to delete the old /dev/xvda1 partition, move /dev/xvda2 to the start of the disk and expand it to fill the entire disk.

Fortunately, this is quite easy to do in the GUI gparted partition editor.  It's entirely possible to do it from the command line with `parted` but much easier in `gparted`.

All of this will result in a single partition /dev/xvda1 with size 158 GB.

When the partition has been moved and resized, you will probably need to re-run grub-install to install the boot-loader again.  Mount the partition as /mnt again and:

```
for i in proc dev sys ; do mount -o bind /$i /mnt/$i ; done
chroot /mnt
grub-install /dev/xvda
exit
for i in proc dev sys / ; do umount /mnt/$i ; done
```

Comment: I'll chk for your mentioned steps. But is there any other way where I don't don't need to reboot server?

Comment: Not really.  If you had enough space on xvda1 to hold everything in /opt then you could `mkdir /opt/new ; mv /opt/* /opt.new`, unmount /opt, `rmdir /opt ; mv /opt.new /opt`.  you'd then be able to run `parted` or `fdisk` to delete xvda2 and resize xvda1, and then resize the filesystem on xvda1 (resize2fs can grow but not shrink a mounted ext2/3/4 filesystem)

Comment: If you had a USB stick or a network drive or something to temporarily store everything in /opt, that would work too.  In either case, you'd need to kill anything that was had open files or was writing to /opt first.

Comment: actually, when i said `/opt` above, i meant `/opt/xxxx` - i misread your question and thought xvda2 was /opt rather than /opt/xxxx.  that applies to everything i said in my answer too.